# Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void'

Tags: swift

I can't solve this error I hope  can I find the solution here
the error is in the line 22 and it's "Cannot convert value of type `()` to expected argument type `(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void`"

[image]

```
struct WeatherManager {
    let weatherURL = ""
    func fetchWeather(cityName : String){
        let urlString = "\(weatherURL)&q=\(cityName)"
        performRequest(urlString: urlString)
    }
    func performRequest(urlString : String){
        //1- Create a URL
        if let url = URL(string: urlString){
            //2- Create a URLSession
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            //3- Give the session a task
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler:handel(data: <#T##Data?#>, urlSession: <#T##URLSession?#>, error: <#T##Error?#>))
            //4- Start the Task
            task.resume()
        }
    }
    func handel(data:Data? , urlSession : URLSession? , error : Error?){
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        if let safeData = data{
            let dataString = String(data: safeData, encoding: .utf8)
            print(dataString!)
        }
    }
}
```

here is the error :

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler:handel(data: <#T##Data?#>, urlSession: <#T##URLSession?#>, error: <#T##Error?#>))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few observations:

1. The signature of “handle” is incorrect. The second parameter is a `URLResponse`, not a `URLSession`:

   ```swift
   func handle(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) {
       if let error = error {
           print(error)
           return
       }
       if let data = data, let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
           print(string)
       }
   }
   ```

   As Leo pointed out, you should avoid force-unwrapping with the `!` operator, too (especially when converting the `Data` to a UTF8 `String`).
2. You should not supply parameters when you pass `handle` to `dataTask`:

   ```swift
   func performRequest(urlString: String) {
       //1- Create a URL
       guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
       //2- Use existing URLSession
       let session = URLSession.shared // (configuration: .default)
       //3- Give the session a task
       let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: handle)
       //4- Start the Task
       task.resume()
   }
   ```

---

Unrelated, please note that I have *not* created a `URLSession` in `performRequest`. Sessions will leak memory if you create them but do not invalidate them. In this case, it is easier to use the existing `shared` session, rather than creating a new one.

If you *really* needed to create one (which you obviously do not in this case ... use `shared` instead), you would explicitly tell it to invalidate itself when the request was done.

```swift
func performRequest(urlString: String) {
    //1- Create a URL
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
    //2- Create URLSession (but only if absolutely necessary)
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    //3- Give the session a task
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: handle)
    //4- Start the Task
    task.resume()
    //5- If you really must create a session, invalidate it when the request(s) are finished
    session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
}
```

But this is an anti-pattern because it is so inefficient. You should reuse a single session, like shown in the previous code snippet, if at all possible.